# Find minimum number of edges/vertices to add or remove to transform a graph from 1 to another

Tags: python, nodes, graph-theory, edges, vertices

Given 1 graph (A) and another graph (B) , minimum number of edges and vertice to add or remove such that you can get from graph A to graph B.

Current Approach: Find the number of vertices that are present in graph A but not in graph B. Both the graphs can have branches. In the example it's a linked list but it doesn't always need to be like that. Then remove all those vertices, then remove all the edges that dont exist in A but are present in B. Then add vertices that are present in  graph A but not in graph B. Then add edges that are not present. However, this approach doesnt take in consideration the subgraph method, but just edge by Edge. The issue is that graph A can have multiple same nodes:

```
A - B - A - A - B - C 

graph B: 

B - B - A 

B   B - A
```

But now I am not sure which B should I add the A-B, i.e. not sure  which B corresponds from graph B to graph A. In the example it is the second B that corresponds with the first B in graph A.  I have been working on this for the past 2 days and I am stuck here. This is not a homework, its a problem I have been working on. Any help will be appreciated. A premade library in python would also help. Thanks

Comment: That's a solved problem, I believe. I seem to remember a solution in Steven Skiena's Algorithm Design Manual.